# Build Kibana 4 executable jar from source in Github

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I wanted to try the latest Kibana 4 from Github and also possibly tweak it a little for our use. What is the process to build and pack Kibana 4's Executable jar including its server from the source on Github? At present the only available release is Kibana 4 beta 1 on Elasticsearch website.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to build it from source. The instructions are here: https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md